# Почему в генераторе удаляются значения?

Tags: python, python-3.x, генераторы

Есть функция, ей на вход подается значение типа `float` `55.03055555555556`. Далее из файла считываю набор строк и убираю лишнее.

```
def append_in_file(string):
    string = str(string)
    flag = True
    with open("times", mode="r") as f:
        print([i.replace("\n", "").replace("\'", '') for i in f.readlines()])
        print([i.replace("\n", "").replace("\'", '') for i in f.readlines()])
        if string in [i.replace("\n", "").replace("\'", '') for i in f.readlines()]:
            print(f"Время {string} уже было записано")
            flag = False
    if flag:
        with open("times", mode="a") as f:
            f.write(f"{string}\n")
```

Почему она дает такой вывод?

```
['55.03055555555556', '55.03055555555556', '55.03055555555556', '55.03055555555556', '55.03055555555556', '55.03055555555556', '55.03055555555556', '55.03055555555556']
[]
```

То есть почему на 5 строке создается нормальный список, а на 6 пустой.
Если делаю тоже самоe в `IDLE`, то сколько бы раз я не запускал генератор, то ничего не меняется (как в моем понимании и должно работать)

```
>>> m = ['55.03055555555556', '55.03055555555556', '55.03055555555556', '55.03055555555556', '55.03055555555556', '55.03055555555556', '55.03055555555556']
>>> [i.replace("\n", "").replace("\'", '') for i in m]
['55.03055555555556', '55.03055555555556', '55.03055555555556', '55.03055555555556', '55.03055555555556', '55.03055555555556', '55.03055555555556']
>>> [i.replace("\n", "").replace("\'", '') for i in m]
['55.03055555555556', '55.03055555555556', '55.03055555555556', '55.03055555555556', '55.03055555555556', '55.03055555555556', '55.03055555555556']
```

Comment: Потому что первый `f.readlines()` уже считал полностью весь файл, и во втором `f.readlines()` уже нечего читать, потому что файл кончился

Comment: readlines() читает весь файл сразу, до конца

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже написали в комментариях, после первого цикла файловый указатель стоит в конце файла, поэтому дальнейшее чтение невозможно. Вы можете передвинуть указатель в начало с помощью `f.seek(0)`

После этого вы снова сможете считывать данные, как если бы вы открыли файл заново.